# Unable to Calculate 7 Day Moving Average due to inconsistent dates

Tags: postgresql

I just noticed that my code below is not actually a 7 day moving avg, and instead it is a 7 row moving avg. The dates in my table spans several months and I am trying to iron out since I have inconsistent data flow so I can't expect the last 7 rows of the window function to actually represent a 7 day avg. Thanks.

```
select date, sales, 
avg(sales) over(order by date rows between 6 preceding and current row)
from sales_info
order by date
```

Comment: `... where date in  (select generate_series(current_date - interval '7 days', current_date::timestamp, '1 day')::date) order by date`?

Comment: What version of postgres?  You can use range between instead of rows between, if you are using a sufficiently recent version.

Comment: @Jeremy I am using PostgreSQL 13.2. Can you go into details about using range between instead of rows between?

Comment: @Jeremy Thank you so much. I greatly appreciate it. Seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a bit closer to a true 7 day moving average by using RANGE instead of ROWS for your range specification.

Read more about window function frames [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS).

I believe this should work for you:

```
select date, sales, 
avg(sales) over(order by date range between '6 days' preceding and current row)
from sales_info
order by date;
```

Here's a demonstration with made up data:

```
SELECT i, 
       t, 
       avg(i) OVER (ORDER BY t RANGE BETWEEN '6 days' preceding and current row) FROM (
       SELECT i, t
       FROM generate_series('2021-01-01'::timestamp, '2021-02-01'::timestamp, '1 day') WITH ORDINALITY as g(t, i)
) sub;
 i  |          t          |          avg
----+---------------------+------------------------
  1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 1.00000000000000000000
  2 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 |     1.5000000000000000
  3 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 |     2.0000000000000000
  4 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 |     2.5000000000000000
  5 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 |     3.0000000000000000
  6 | 2021-01-06 00:00:00 |     3.5000000000000000
  7 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 |     4.0000000000000000
  8 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 |     5.0000000000000000
  9 | 2021-01-09 00:00:00 |     6.0000000000000000
 10 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 |     7.0000000000000000
 11 | 2021-01-11 00:00:00 |     8.0000000000000000
 12 | 2021-01-12 00:00:00 |     9.0000000000000000
 13 | 2021-01-13 00:00:00 |    10.0000000000000000
 14 | 2021-01-14 00:00:00 |    11.0000000000000000
 15 | 2021-01-15 00:00:00 |    12.0000000000000000
 16 | 2021-01-16 00:00:00 |    13.0000000000000000
 17 | 2021-01-17 00:00:00 |    14.0000000000000000
 18 | 2021-01-18 00:00:00 |    15.0000000000000000
 19 | 2021-01-19 00:00:00 |    16.0000000000000000
 20 | 2021-01-20 00:00:00 |    17.0000000000000000
 21 | 2021-01-21 00:00:00 |    18.0000000000000000
 22 | 2021-01-22 00:00:00 |    19.0000000000000000
 23 | 2021-01-23 00:00:00 |    20.0000000000000000
 24 | 2021-01-24 00:00:00 |    21.0000000000000000
 25 | 2021-01-25 00:00:00 |    22.0000000000000000
 26 | 2021-01-26 00:00:00 |    23.0000000000000000
 27 | 2021-01-27 00:00:00 |    24.0000000000000000
 28 | 2021-01-28 00:00:00 |    25.0000000000000000
 29 | 2021-01-29 00:00:00 |    26.0000000000000000
 30 | 2021-01-30 00:00:00 |    27.0000000000000000
 31 | 2021-01-31 00:00:00 |    28.0000000000000000
 32 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 |    29.0000000000000000
```